# Js Keyboard listening

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

my goal to this one is when u type the search bar will pop up the code below is working but i have a problem while typing into different input for example the comment input the js listen and open the search bar. is it possible when im already in a different input field the search will not pop up and show.

```
<style>
#searchBar { display: none;    -webkit-transition: width 2s; /* Safari */ transition: width 2s;}
.search { width: 250px; height: 20px; }
</style>

<script>
window.onload = function() {
    var listen = /^[a-z0-9]+$/i;
    var searchInput = document.getElementById('searchInput');
    var searchBar = document.getElementById('searchBar');

    if ( window.addEventListener )
        window.addEventListener( 'keyup', insertKey, false);

    function insertKey( e ) {
        // Get the character from e.keyCode
        var key = String.fromCharCode( e.keyCode ).toLowerCase(); 

        // Match the character
        if( key.match(listen) ) {

            // Change display: none; to display: block;
            searchBar.style.display = "block";
            // Append every new character
            searchInput.value += key;
            // Focus on input
            searchInput.focus();

            // Since you focused on the input you don't need to listen for keyup anymore.
            window.removeEventListener( 'keyup', insertKey );

            // I didn't tested with jQuery
            // $('#searchBar').fadeIn();
            // $('#searchBar input').append(keys);
            // $('#searchBar input').focus();
        }
    }
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

When you add an event listener to `window` for the `keyup` event, it will trigger when a `keyup` is detected no matter where it originates from. You aren't being discriminatory enough about what events you're listening to.

One solution is to add the event listener directly to the `input` elements, so that a `keyup` from one element doesn't trigger another element's listener:

```
document.getElementById("searchInput").addEventListener("keyup", searchInputKeyHandler);
document.getElementById("commentInput").addEventListener("keyup", commentInputKeyHandler);
// etc.
```

This works but is a bit weird. If all you're doing is listening for a user typing in an `input` HTML element, then a better event to listen for is `input` which triggers whenever an `input` element has its value changed.

```
document.getElementById("searchInput").addEventListener("input", searchInputKeyHandler);
document.getElementById("commentInput").addEventListener("input", commentInputKeyHandler);
// etc.
```

Some elements can also listen for a `change` event; do some research and see what event is most appropriate for your use case.